# Refund transaction of Paypal recurring billing

Tags: ajax, api, paypal, recurring-billing

I am trying to create a refund for a transaction that happened over a recurring billing agreement using AJAX but I keep getting errors like 404, 501, and 500 errors. All my other API calls to Paypal's sandbox come back successfully. I am getting the transaction ID from a get request that returns an array of transactions (`/v1/payments/billing-agreements/<Agreement-Id>/transactions?start_date=yyyy-mm-dd&end_date=yyyy-mm-dd`). Do any of you know if this is an issue with my API call or if Paypal doesn't allow refunds on recurring billing? Also if there is a way to just return money back to the customer using Paypal's RESTful API that would also be feedback.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We are having exactly the same issue. It seems that regular sale transactions can be refunded but we're getting an error attempting to refund a subscription agreement transaction.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the search transactions API call, it'll return a few different fields with transaction_id. You will have ones for when the agreement is agreed to or modified. These will generally have 'I-' at the beginning. These are not refundable. But, they will also provide ones with the status "completed" that are for the actual payments. These are the ones that can be refunded.

If you are refunding the "I-" ones, you will get the INVALID RESOURCE ID error.

Comment: You're exactly right. I have been using the transaction IDs with the status complete. I have tried using transaction IDs from one time transactions and those work, but any time I try using a recurring billing transaction ID I get the response `"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID"`

Comment: For testing purposes, can you try using the /v1/payments/capture/<Capture-Id>/refund API instead?  For recurring payments, like this, it's not a sale or an authorization...it lists it as a Recurring Payment type, or which I do not see a refund method.

Comment: I get the same error if I use `/v1/payments/capture/<Capture-Id>/refund`. I agree with you on that it isn't a sale or a capture. But there's got to be some way to refund a recurring billing transaction

Comment: hi, I am having the same issue for paypal subscription payments. I have a completed test transaction. 
`transaction_id   : 4D142018GM6180709
status     : Completed
transaction_type  : Recurring Payment
amount  {2}
  currency : HKD
  value  : 1.00
fee_amount  {2}
 currency : HKD
 value  : -1.00
net_amount  {2}
 currency : HKD
 value  : 0.00
payer_email : admin-buyer@use2pay.com
payer_name : buyer test
time_stamp : 2015-10-07T11:45:08Z
time_zone : GMT`  
I tried `fetchTransaction` method and the "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID" also occurs.

Comment: @AnthonyUmpad I contacted Paypal directly on this issue and they said that as of right now you cannot refund transactions that have happened during a recurring billing plan. They said they added this functionality to be prioritized for a future release of their API. I switched from using Paypal directly to using Braintree, you should check it out! It makes server side configuration easy and it makes it easy to be PCI Compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the transaction id and not the agreement id. This is because the refund API Call is for a transaction not an entire billing agreement. As long as the transaction was in the last 60 days you will be able to refund it.

The below code is directly from the PayPal Developer [Rest API Refund Section](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#refund-a-sale):

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/<Transaction-Id>/refund \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json'  \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>' \
-d '{
  "amount":
  {
    "total": "2.34",
    "currency": "USD"
  }
}'
```

Comment: I've been using the transaction ID I get when I search for the agreement transactions. I get the ID straight off of the `transaction-id` key. The response I get is a 404 with the name of the error being `"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID"`. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Can you provide the request code? I want to make certain you are using the correct endpoint. Usually when you get that error either there is something missing in the request or an invalid transaction id or pay id.

Comment: Here is the request: `POST /v1/payments/sale/0G416629682867447/refund HTTP/1.1
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "amount":
        {
            "total": "2.34",
            "currency": "USD"
        }
}`

It works when I use a transaction ID from a one time transaction however.